# Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I am getting this error when I try to run my app on my old physical device and emulator (both API 19). However, when I run on my main physical device (API 23) and emulators of API 22 and above I get no error.

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
08-19 19:19:54.615 2799-2799/com.nicoqueijo.android.baseconverter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.nicoqueijo.android.baseconverter, PID: 2799
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nicoqueijo.android.baseconverter/com.nicoqueijo.android.baseconverter.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class SeekBar
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class SeekBar
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                        at com.nicoqueijo.android.baseconverter.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/custom_thumb.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020055
                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
                                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.<init>(AbsSeekBar.java:73)
                                                                                        at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:83)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar.<init>(AppCompatSeekBar.java:46)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar.<init>(AppCompatSeekBar.java:42)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:139)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                        at com.nicoqueijo.android.baseconverter.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
                                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
                                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:970)
                                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
                                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2097)
                                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.<init>(AbsSeekBar.java:73) 
                                                                                        at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:83) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar.<init>(AppCompatSeekBar.java:46) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar.<init>(AppCompatSeekBar.java:42) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:139) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                        at com.nicoqueijo.android.baseconverter.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It's being caused by line 78 on my main activity xml layout which is this code:

```
<SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekbar_from_controller"
                    style="@style/SeekBarStyle"/>
```

This traces back to my seekbar style which is as follow:

```
<style name="SeekBarStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:max">14</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:progress">1</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/custom_thumb</item>
    </style>
```

But then this traces back to my custom_thumb.xml which is this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>
    <solid android:color="?colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

I know the problem is that I'm using "?colorPrimary" because I tried removing this and putting a hard-coded color and then when I run it it causes an error again but on another element which has the color as "?colorPrimary".

Is there a way to fix this without using hard-coded colors? I need to use "?colorPrimary" because I have options to change the theme of the app and this changes the primary, accent, and primaryDark colors.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and correct the indentations? I'm talking especially about the first code section: the stack trace is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Comment: That won't work because I was using different colors as primary. What I had to do it is make a duplicate layout file but without using ?colorPrimary in the styles and have APIs lower than or equal to 19 call set the layout to that.

if (SystemInfo.isRunningLollipopOrHigher()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_static_theme);
        }